# Evaluate Higher Order Homogenous Differential Equation $ (D^4 - D^3)y=0; y(0) = 1 = y'(0), y''(1) = 3e, y'''(1) = e $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I'm getting following values of constants:

$C1 = 0$

$ C2 = 0$

$C3 = e$

$ C4 = 1$

But in my solution manual of the book, the constant values are coming like this:

$C1 = 0$

$ C2 = 0$

$C3 = 1$

$ C4 = 1$

I wanted to know if I am doing it wrong or there's some printing mistake in the solution manual of the book I have got?

Update:

Here's my procedure:

$D^3(D-1) = 0$

$D=0,0,0,1$

$y = c_1 + c_2x+c_3x^2+c_4e^x$

$y' = c_2+2c_3x+c_4e^x$

$y'' = 2c_3+c_4e^x$

$y''' = c_4e^x$

Comment: What are your four linearly independent solutions and which of your constants go with which solution?

Comment: Note also that this is not an initial value problem, so here is no guarantee of a unique solution.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Respected Professor, I've updated my question with the general equations that I've got before substituting values given in question.

Comment: In your next to last equation, you accidentally wrote $e^e$ rather than $e^x$. I suspect you merely made an algebra mistake while evaluating the constants. When I worked it I got $c_1=c_2=0$, $c_3=e$ and $c_4=1$. Notice that you will have $2c_3+c_4e=3e$ and at that point you already know that $c_4=1$ so you get $2c_3+e=3e$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Thank you professor, I was having confusion in the value of $c_3$, I thought there's some kinda exponent property that might had have made the $c_3 = 0$, Actually tomorrow is my exam so I wanted to confirm. Thanks a lot for clearing my doubts.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed, you got the same answer I got. I misremembered your question. Your book gave $c_3=1$ rather than $c_3=e$. I will double-check but I believe I worked it correctly which would mean that your book is wrong. It happens. I always told my students that when a professor writes a textbook he/she sometimes assigns the solutions to graduate students who buy a keg and spend the weekend working the exercises.

Comment: I double-checked. You are right, your book is wrong. You can always just find the derivatives of your solution and see if they meet the conditions.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Ah I see, Thank You Professor, you're a great teacher!

Answer (score 0):

I have come to the same result, the book is obviously wrong:

C1=0

C2=0

C3=e

C4=1